# Is additional damage from a spell counted as part of the same attack?

Tags: spells, dnd-5e, damage, attack, critical-hit

Is additional damage from a spell counted as part of the same attack?

For a specific example, let's look at [*witch bolt*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/witch-bolt) (PHB, page 289). There may be others, but I am far too lazy to look through each and every one for other examples. *Witch bolt* says:

> Make a ranged spell attack against that creature. On a hit, the target takes 1d12 lightning damage, and on each of your turns for the duration, you can use your action to deal 1d12 lightning damage to the target automatically.

In connection with [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/48997/paralyzed-enemy-and-witch-bolt-auto-crit-on-a-hit), **if you were to score a *critical hit* on the initial attack roll for *witch bolt*, would the additional damage rolls on your other turns be counted as part of the same attack and thus also be critical hits?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, the additional damage isn't part of the same attack.

I don't think there is quite a rule that covers this. But the damage from *witch bolt*'s add on feature would be counted the same way as other kinds of no-save damage is counted (*magic missile*, for example). It's not a part of the attack roll's damage roll, and thus is not doubled if you roll a critical on the original attack.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not part of the same attack.

The key is that it does 1d12 damage on the first strike, then an additional 1d12 on subsequent turns for the duration. That means each subsequent damage gets a separate 1d12 roll and is not part of the original attack roll. Your critical is associated with the attack roll, not with the damage roll, it just modifies the damage under the crit rules.

It would be different if the text said "...on each of your turns for the duration, you can use your action to deal the same amount of lightning damage to the target automatically".